# Эффективное запоминание индексов последовательности

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Со стандартного input-потока ситается последовательность, состоящая из очень большого количества чисел, которые, в свою очередь, являются целыми и могут принимать значения из диапазона [`0`, `MAX_INT`). Задача состоит в том, чтобы в этой последовательности отыскать наикратчайшее (с наименьшим кол-вом элементов) подмножество, сумма элементов которого *максимальна и нечётна*.
Подмножество не обязательно должно быть отрезком из целевого, т.е может быть и "рваным".

Собственно, проблема состоит в том, как можно наиболее эффективно получить индексы элементов этого самого подмножества в целевом и в порядке возрастания? 
*Элементы при этом сохранять где-либо внутри программы не следует.* Буду очень благодарен за любые идеи! При анализе помните о "числовой объемности" целевого множества!

Краткий пример для наглядности:

```
последовательность:  [1]->0 [2]->13 [3]->202
результат         :  2 3
```

Comment: приведите хоть  пару вариантов-примеров. Потому что "максимальная сумма и минимальная длина плохо совместимы между собой. К пример, вот такая последовательность - 2 4 5 3 1 2 10. В этом случае 5 - это минимальная последовательность, но явно не максимальная. 5 3 1 - сумма будет побольше, но явно последовательность не минимальная.

Скорее всего нужно просто выбрать все нечетные числа, если их четное кол-во - выбросить минимальное.

Comment: @KoVadim, пример готов. Да, ход мысли правильный, но могут также присутствовать нули( и довольно много ).

Comment: тогда просто набираете четных по максимум, нули - пропускаете, нечетных нужно нечетное количество (если их четное, выбрасываем минимальное).

Comment: Чётные числа в результирующем подмножестве тоже не помешают, если сумма нечётных будет нечётна.

Comment: @KoVadim, достаточно будет просто выкинуть все "0", и если (результирующая сумма)%2 будет =0, то надо будет просто вычесть минимальное нечетное. Но надо эффективно получить индексы того, что входит/не входит..

Answer (score 2):

Из набора неотрицательных целых чисел выбрать поднабор с наибольшей возможной нечётной суммой, среди равных выбрать наикратчайший?

Взять все имеющиеся числа кроме нулей. Если получилась чётная сумма, выкинуть минимальное нечётное. Если такого нет (т. е. все числа набора чётные), то набрать требуемую сумму невозможно.

Comment: Не хочу показаться грубым, но, может быть, вы попытаетесь прочитать  и понять задачу еще раз?

Comment: @0xFFh, да пропустил "наикратчайший". Поправил ответ.

Comment: Все равно, это мало что меняет: задача - получить индексы. Пускай мы проигнорируем нули, но, сами подумайте, что если минимальное нечётное будет стоять в самом начале/в середине/конце...?

Comment: Не понял, какая разница, где оно находится. Задача решается за 1 полный проход, если порядок индексов не важен и за 2 полных прохода, если важен.

Comment: Здесь моя промашка: подразумевалось, что значения нельзя запоминать внутрипрограммно. Они, предположим, читаются с input-потока. Т.е вариант с двойным проходом отпадает..

Comment: @0xFFh Двойной проход не нужен. Во время первого и единственного прохода можно одновременно собирать индексы всех ненулевых элементов, считать чётность суммы и искать индекс минимального  нечётного элемента. В конце нужно просто выкинуть индекс минимального нечётного, если сумма окажется чётной.

Comment: @Shamov, ну, разумеется. Проблема ведь не в этом, а в запоминании этих индексов...если нулей будет очень много(или очень мало), то решение будет неэффективно.

Comment: @0xFFh Тогда я не понимаю задачу. Уточняйте условие. Видимо, есть какой-то важный нюанс, который вы знаете, а мы - нет.

Comment: @0xFFh Я наконец-то понял, в чём проблема. Нужно не просто найти индексы, а ещё и компактно их хранить. Вам нужна структура, которая называется "дерево интервалов".

Comment: Способ хранения должен зависеть от дальнейшего использования, а не от потребления памяти. Если конечно речь не идёт о том, что памяти просто не хватит.